# Get rid of a large gap in CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am new to Android. In my CardView, TextView is displayed at the bottom. However, my requirement is right below of the ImageView.

Showed in the below picture, I want to move my text up to the orange position.

XML code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.01dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"           
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_nature"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:textColor="#24B9FE"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_nature"
        android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
        android:background="#24B9FE"
        android:text="Book"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Comment: didn't understand the Question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this attribute of the ImageView:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
```

Because this setting makes large gap between the ImageView and the TextView and Button.

**EDIT**

In addtion to deleting above attribute, if you want the TextView in the vertical middle position,
you may get that by setting a certain equivalent margin to both of layout_marginTop and layout_marginBottom of the TextView and Button.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    ...
```

Comment: how to align my text center of the gap @hata